# How to catch nodelet shutdown signal?

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a new thread in a nodelet which runs some task until the nodelet is shutdown. But I don't know how to let the new thread know when the nodelet is shutting down, so for now it will make the whole nodelet_manager crash when I only wants to end that nodelet.

I tried to use getPrivateNodeHandle() to get the ros::NodeHandle instance, and use nodehandle.ok() to test whether the new thread should stop, sometimes it works, but sometimes not.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12441/how-to-catch-nodelet-shutdown-signal?/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should signal any threads started in the destructor and wait to join them before exiting the destructor.

For an example take a look at the [camera1394 nodelet destructor.](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/0bf2801957b451c274d1bf5909ab1539b6ef8f5e/src/nodes/nodelet.cpp#L61)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2011-12-24**:
Thanks! It's a good example

**Comment by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on 2014-11-21**:
I'm not really sure if the destructor is being called correctly since I try to use ROS_INFO_STREAM or std::cout and I see nothing printed.